# dart query Steam Master Server

Tags: dart, server, udp, steam

I am trying to get the server IPs from a steam master server via a query and later query the game servers.
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Master_Server_Query_Protocol#

There are plenty of examples in different programming languages but not dart.
https://gist.github.com/koenbollen/645947/09241258c0d2dd8d5a4e647865730ab83955f68b#file-mastersteam-py-L18

My problem is: i don't even understand why the address "hl2master.steampowered.com" is an invalid internet address. It says so on the official valve Master Server Query (link at top of the post).

This is the error i get trying to run the code:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address hl2master.steampowered.com

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

// Master server:
const GOLD_SRC = "hl1master.steampowered.com";
const GOLD_SRC_PORT = 27010;

const SOURCE = "hl2master.steampowered.com";
const SOURCE_PORT = 27011;

// Regions:
const US_EAST_COAST = 0x00;
const US_WEST_COAST = 0x01;
const SOUTH_AMERICA = 0x02;
const EUROPE        = 0x03;
const ASIA          = 0x04;
const AUSTRALIA     = 0x05;
const MIDDLE_EAST   = 0x06;
const AFRICA        = 0x07;
const ALL           = 0xFF;



class MasterServerQuery {
  connectSocket01() async {
    var message = "31 FF 30 2E 30 2E 30 2E";
    InternetAddress master = InternetAddress(SOURCE);
    var masterPort = SOURCE_PORT;
    RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 4096).then((
        RawDatagramSocket socket) {
      print('UDP Echo ready to receive');
      print('${socket.address.address}:${socket.port}');
      socket.listen((RawSocketEvent e) {
        Datagram d = socket.receive();
        if (d == null) return;

        String message = "31 FF 30 2E 30 2E 30 2E";
        print(
            'Datagram from ${d.address.address}:${d.port}: ${message.trim()}');

        socket.send(message.codeUnits, master, masterPort);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address is not valid, since it expects a valid ip address and not an hostname, you can provide the ip address or use `InternetAddress.lookup`.

You code is also wrong in the way that you pass the message you shouldn't pass the codeUnits but the bytes in a way as such:

```
  final byteData = ByteData(8);
  byteData.setUint8(0, 0x31);
  byteData.setUint8(1, 0xFF);
  byteData.setUint8(2, 0x30);
  byteData.setUint8(3, 0x2E);
  byteData.setUint8(4, 0x30);
  byteData.setUint8(5, 0x2E);
  byteData.setUint8(6, 0x30);
  byteData.setUint8(7, 0x2E);
  byteData.buffer.asUint8List() //Pass this.
```

Comment: How does that work with strings? Like with the A2S_INFO

Comment: You should encode the string in uft8 and then set the bytes. However if you plan to use the query protocol (not master) or the rcon I've already made an implementation. [example for A2S_INFO](https://github.com/Hexer10/source_query_rcon/blob/master/lib/src/query_socket.dart#L157-L167), [query package](https://pub.dev/packages/source_server)